# Xamarin Push Notification Problem About Certificates

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have searched and tried various resources on the internet for Xamarin IOS certificate transactions, but I cannot do anything.
I log into the Apple developer account and create the certificates for the iOS application, but I cannot upload it to the device while compiling it in visual studio. I constantly get a certificate error.
The iPhone Developer certificate is not visible in visual studio.
It appears to be untitled in XCode.
I use Azure APNS for notifications, I created a hub, completed the certificates, removed the necessary parts to the application, but when I send the notification, it says it was sent to 0 devices.

I would be glad if you help..

This's the settings in iOS.Properties Bundle Signing

[image]

This's the output when I tried to debug on my Device iPhone 7

```
1>  takikuyumculuk.iOS -> C:\Users\Onur\source\repos\takikuyumculuk\takikuyumculuk\takikuyumculuk.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\takikuyumculuk.iOS.exe
1>  Detected signing identity:
1>          
1>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Distribution: Onur In (H3RQ5434VA)" (FB4A14A5D8838F9C9DD69BCDE1E5601DBC7B29A3)
1>    Provisioning Profile: "TakiAppDist" (b41a4161-0831-40e6-8be6-c05640a48ea4)
1>    Bundle Id: com.takikuyumculuk.apple
1>    App Id: H3RQ5434VA.com.takikuyumculuk.apple
1>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil -num-threads 4 -z -o bin/iPhone/Debug/takikuyumculuk.iOS.app.dSYM bin/iPhone/Debug/takikuyumculuk.iOS.app/takikuyumculuk.iOS 
1>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -i -s obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-symbols.list bin/iPhone/Debug/takikuyumculuk.iOS.app/takikuyumculuk.iOS 
1>  /usr/bin/mdimport bin/iPhone/Debug/takikuyumculuk.iOS.app/../ 
1>  /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv "-R=anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)" bin/iPhone/Debug/takikuyumculuk.iOS.app 
2>Not all the required processes could be started on the paired Mac. Please check the Xamarin output pane for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Hi, first you could check AppID whether contain the push service, have a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/ios-sdk-get-started#register-your-app-for-push-notifications) to check whehter **Register your app for push notifications**. Then also need to be sure that has [created a certificate for Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/ios-sdk-get-started#create-a-certificate-for-notification-hubs).

Answer (score 0):

*ALL* the Azure/MS documentation for Xamarin ios notifications is inaccurate and badly out of date. The code samples will not work reliably with the latest versions of the libraries.

1. Do not use SBNotificationHub, use MSNotificationHub
2. Make sure you have 2 hubs, one for development, one for production. Delete all registrations from any existing hubs or just create new hubs.
3. You need to manually change the Entitlements.plist XML to add either production or development here:

> ```
>   <key>aps-environment</key>
> <string>production</string>
> ```

5. Do not allow a development registration on a production hub , or a production registration on a sandbox hub, as you'll need to clear out all registrations or recreate the hub
6. Use the [guidance here](https://github.com/azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin) It is the only current working documentation. SBNotificationHub has bugs, MSNotificationHub has a better model.
7. Use tokens in the hub APNS config, it's easier.